# Hyperledger composer Permission for array of Participants

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am creating an asset in Hyperledger composer as shown below. I want to add participants in Bank[] array (these banks will only have read only access). In Permission.acl file **how can I write condition for checking into the array(Bank[]) if the participant exist** for this asset(Read only).

ASSET DEFINITION:

```
asset Details identified by detailsId {
    o String detailsId
    o String description optional
    --> Bank owner
    --> Bank[] access optional
    o String document 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like below - a) if its not empty and b) if the participant from the bank is authorised (by checking the array) - if so, allow READ access (if I read you correctly).

```
rule checkParticipant {
    description: "check Participant is from allowed Bank"
    participant(p): "org.acme.account.BankTeller"
    operation: READ
    resource(v): "org.acme.account.Details"
    condition: ( v.access && v.access.indexOf(p.getIdentifier()) > -1 )
    action: ALLOW
}
```

or a condition (something like below) if case is an issue:

```
condition: ( v.access && v.access.toLowerCase().indexOf(p.getIdentifier().toLowerCase()) > -1 )
```

Comment: I will try what you have told and will let you know if any error occurs.

Comment: v.access.indexOf(p.getIdentifier()) > -1 is to check that array should have the participant but what v.access is for?

Comment: like saying the `access` array is not null (it is optional after all)

Answer (score 1):

This rule should do the trick, though your namespace is likely different.  Assumes that you have other rules in place to allow access to the Bank participant registry.

```
rule AllowAccessToBankInArray {
description: "Allow access "
participant(p): "com.example.Bank"
operation: ALL
resource(r): "com.example.Details"
condition: (
   r.access.some(function (bank) {
      return bank.getIdentifier() === p.getIdentifier();  
      } )
   )
```

Comment: I will try this.