# hyperledger composer adding Participants to array of Participants in transaction process

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I have defined **Participant** and **asset** as below and I want to add a particular participant to array of access[type Participant] in transaction. Can someone tell me how this can be done.

How can I add the participant identity to the array. How do I need to pass the identity through params and then add it to the array of participants. I have created the permissions according to the question I asked earlier. [Link to the question for permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51815370/hyperledger-composer-permission-for-array-of-participants/51821095?noredirect=1#comment90603638_51821095)

**ASSET DECLARATION**

```
asset Details identified by detailsId {
     o String detailsId
     o String description optional
     --> Bank owner
     o Bank[] access optional
     o String document 
}
```

**PARTCIPANT DECLARATION**

```
participant Bank identified by bankId {
   o String bankId
   o String Name
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have made a small change to the model between the ACL example and this example - changing the access array which was a relationship before.

```
--> Bank[] access optional    original
  vs
o Bank[] access optional      here
```

Based on the **original model**, first add this Transaction to the model:

```
transaction AddAccess {
  --> Details details
  --> Bank additionalAccess
}
```

Then, this scripted Transaction should work for you:

```
/**
 * Adding a Bank to an access list
 * @param {org.example.test.AddAccess} addA 
 * @transaction
 */
async function addAccess(addA) { 

  // Add the new access to the array, checking if empty first as it is optional field at creation
  if (typeof addA.details.access == 'undefined') {
    addA.details.access = new Array();
    addA.details.access[0] = addA.additionalAccess;
  } 
  else {
    addA.details.access.push(addA.additionalAccess);
  }

  // get the Registry
  const assetRegistry = await getAssetRegistry('org.example.test.Details');

  // Update the Registry with the new details
  await assetRegistry.update(addA.details);
}
```

Test with JSON like this:

```
{
  "$class": "org.example.test.AddAccess",
  "details": "resource:org.example.test.Details#D11",
  "additionalAccess": "resource:org.example.test.Bank#9241"
}
```

Comment: Should it be a relationship or not?

Comment: yes, should be a relationship, as this matches what you had in your ACLs from your earlier link.  As per @rthatcher above `--> Bank[] access optional ` would host an array of relationship identifiers, which your ACLs already check.

Comment: @PaulO'Mahony Please complete your answer at this linked question also. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51743406/how-to-store-large-file-in-hyperledger-fabric-using-hyperledger-composer/51745468#51745468)